# How to place a custom control within a cells of datagridview in window form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i'm developing a window form application.

i'm in need of placing custom control comprising of two labels within the cells of the datagrid view.

i have created the custom controls.Guide me to populate the cells with the custom control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to create your own editing control which implements IDataGridViewEditingControl. See the msdn documentation for [IDataGridViewEditingControl Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol.aspx). There is an example at the bottom.

After you create your own editing control, you may need to create something like this: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)