# add multiple buttons to a datagridviewbuttoncell

Tags: c#, button, datagridviewbuttoncolumn

I would like to add multiple buttons to a datagridviewbuttoncell

imagine 1 column contains a simple integer count

the button column next to it would have 2 buttons, one + and one -

then for example subscribe the click events to increment or decrement the text column counter following if + or - was clicked

is this possible ?

Comment: Why not to add two columns - one for "+" button and one for "-" button?

Comment: yes i thought about that and it works of course ;-) but i think in 1 column is an economy of space and its nicer. I've been searching on google but doesn't look like there's a simpler way than painting the buttons in position which is a pain

Comment: and i think i've seen it being done before though i can't remember where

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can easily modify `DataGridViewButtonCell`. But you can always create your own control and put in a cell like described here: [How to place a custom control within a cells of datagridview in window form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955144/how-to-place-a-custom-control-within-a-cells-of-datagridview-in-window-form)

1) Create custom control, implement `IDataGridViewEditingControl` [IDataGridViewEditingControl Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol.aspx).

2) [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)